# wpf how to get view properties from customized titlebar

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a customized titlebar named bar1.xaml which is reference by a partial view named WindowBase.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/Project1;component/Themes/WPFThemes/Bar1.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

Then each view would reference merge the partial view that includes the titlebar like the following

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/project1;component/View/WindowBase.xaml"/>

        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

Now I would like to get the field value of view object field from custom titlebar Bar1's event such as close button.

```
private void CloseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Window window = this.TemplatedParent as Window;
}
```

From the debugger I can see the field value when I point to window but I have no way to access them in code. Is there any way to do that?

I tried x:FieldModifier="public" but it does not work.

```
    <Button Content="Start"  Name="start" IsEnabled="{Binding StartIsEnabled}" Command="{Binding StartCommand}" Visibility="{Binding StartVisibility}" x:FieldModifier="public"/>
```

Thanks,